# Getting error while running the jmeter script with Ajax Request

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

[image]

Getting this error. I am using the 3rd method from https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter
I have added the executable file in blazemeter-ajax-sampler-1.0-SNAPSHOT in lib/Ext
What should i do to work it properly.
Can I work with it without using blazemeter
Again I checked with Listner View Tree and Found as in fig.
[image]

I am using Example Sampler to handle ajax requests. I have added one get method, url and value. I want to parameterise some string in the url. If I run the script without parameterising the string in the url it works. But it fails when I parameterised it. Can you please help? Please let me know if you need more information.

How to pass values(format) for Post method??

[image]

Also wanted to know how to add values In example sampler??

Comment: Can you attach an image of the complete test plan....?

Answer (score 2):

The mentioned sampler isn't a real AJAX plugin, you can use it as a reference for building your own sampler.

In order to see the request details you need to do the following changes in source code:

- in [AJAXRequest.java](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/ajax-sampler/src/189c0fe372d7285f736ece6741d625b73507c534/src/main/java/com/blazemeter/ajax/AJAXRequest.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) change [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) to [HTTPSampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSampleResult.html)
- use [setRequestHeaders](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setRequestHeaders(java.lang.String)) and [setQueryString](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSampleResult.html#setQueryString(java.lang.String)) methods to store headers and body correspondingly
- the sampler is a "skeleton" so if you need it to be Cookie-, Cache-, Proxy-, etc. -aware you need to add this logic as well.

If it is ok for you to use the sampler in its current state - you can find request details in *jmeter.log* file

See [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more tips on troubleshooting JMeter test.